# How to aceess span directly using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to know how to get access of this [span class="myclass"] in below html structure..

```
        <ul>
    <li class="first">
      <span class="myclass"></span>
      <div class="xx">

        <span></span>
        ........
          </div>
   <li >
      <span class="myclass"></span>
      <div class="xx">

        <span></span>
         ........
      </div>
     </ul>
```

Here I need to write one function in [span class="myclass"], but i cant do it using $(".myclass") [I have few issues] I just want to directly access the span itself.How to do this..?

**EDIT**:the sln by phoenix is working fine..but lets say(just for my knowledge) the structure is

```
  <li >
      <span class="myclass"></span>
      <div class="xx">
        <li>
        <span></span>
       </li>
         ........
      </div>
   </ul>
```

so why the span inside 2 nd li(which is under div) is not getting the ref, is it bcoz they are not in the same level..if I need to access them do I need to do some thing like

```
enter code here
```

$("li").next(".xx").find(li span:first-child )..or something else is there?
Thanks.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't use `$(".myClass")`? I can't really see why that's not an option. Maybe solving your "issues" with that selector is a better answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If span is the first child then you can use

[first-child](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/firstChild)

selector

```
$("li span:first-child");
```

Comment: but then what about 2nd span under 2 nd li..i need to call the function from there also?will it work?

Comment: li.first will not work for 2nd span under 2nd li(it dont have a class)

Comment: @moxn: What I am asking is $("li span:first-child");
 is getting ref of <li >
      <span class="myclass"></span>
but why not <li >
      <span class="myclass"></span>
      <div class="xx">
        <li>
        <span></span>
       </li
span inside this div, this also first child of li...

Comment: @Wondering: I know. This is what I described in the last edit of my post.

Answer (score 4):

```
$("li span.myclass")
```

**EDIT**: Okay then maybe with

```
$("li span:first") //EDIT: Don't do that. See below.
```

*apparently :first [stops after the first hit](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/first). So :first-child is the way to go.*

which will select the first span in every li-element. But this can be tricky in case you have other li-elements with spans inside...

**EDIT**: If you can't use the class you already have, maybe assigning an additional class helps?

```
<span class="myclass newClass"></span>
...
var spans = $("li span.newClass");
```

**EDIT**:
As **phoenix** pointed out

```
$("li span:first-child")
```

returns a list with all span elements that are the first child of a li-element. I don't know if jQuery treats textnodes as child nodes. So if you have a space between **<li>** and **<span>**, this might be counted as the first-child. So check if you have any whitespace between your elements beside line breaks.

Comment: also the function should get call from span(one at a time..its like a expandable panel

Comment: What function should get what? You want to call a function for each span? use $.each($("li span:first"), function(i, val){...});

Comment: Or a better question: Why can't you use the class attribute?