# how to access inner span tag in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a HTML structure:

```
            <div class="mydiv">xx
               <span>test1</span>
               <span>test2</span>
              <div class="inerdiv">
                 <span>inner span</span>
               </div>
               </div>
             <span>test3</span>
```

Now I want to apply styling to the span which contains "inner span" .

```
$(function() {
        $(".mydiv").click(function() {

            $(".mydiv").next().find("span").css("border", "1px solid yellow");//not working
        });
    });
```

what should be the proper code?

Comment: Dup? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1606629/how-to-aceess-span-directly-using-jquery/1606637#1606637

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Replace:

```
$(".mydiv").next().find("span").css("border", "1px solid yellow");
```

With:

```
$(".mydiv .innerdiv span").css("border", "1px solid yellow");
```

I don't think `next()` does what you think it does.

[`next()`](http://docs.jquery.com/Traversing/next) returns the immediate next sibling of all previous matched elements.

Given the markup:

```
<div class="hello">foo1</div><span>bar1</span>
<div class="goodbye">foo2</div><span>bar2</span>
<div class="hello">foo3</div><span>bar3</span>
```

The following will return the span elements containing `bar1` and `bar3`:

```
$("div.hello").next()
```

Therefore, there's no way to get the `<div class="innerdiv">` from the outer `div` using `next()`, since they are not siblings.

Comment: agreed. but is there any way to do with next() and find()?
No special reason, just want to know.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function() {
    $(".mydiv").click(function() {

        $(".innerdiv span", this).css("border", "1px solid yellow");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ (.mydiv .inerdiv span:contains('inner span')).css("border", "1px solid yellow")
```